# Responsive styles not working with hover state on different size screens

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I have these styles:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 992px)
{
      .box:hover{
          background-color:#000000;
      }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 993px)
{
      .box:hover{
          background-color:#ffffff;
      }
}
```

When i have a screen between 769px and 992px, the color of the box stays #ffffff when it should go black #000000.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Have you tried a browser inspect utility (Inspector on Firefox, Inspect on Chrome) to see why the unexpected CSS results were rendered?

Comment: it seems to cancel out the hover style from 769px to 992px

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the color of the box stays #ffffff when it should go black #000000."? What change or event causes you to think that the background-color should change and and not stay the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot to add `screen` and the word `and` now is working

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 992px)
  {
   .item_image--products:hover{
      background-color:#000000;
   }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 993px)
{
  .item_image--products:hover{
      background-color:#ffffff;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have seems to work for me (i've changed some stuff for the purpose of this demo but the @media rules are essentially the same)

```css
@media (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  .box {
    background-color: green;
  }
  .box:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .box:after {
    content: " (200-600)";
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .box {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .box:hover {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .box:after {
    content: " (>600)";
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="box">resize yo browser</a>
```